# Confidence interval for LOWESS in Python

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, smoothing, loess

How would I calculate the confidence intervals for a LOWESS regression in Python? I would like to add these as a shaded region to the LOESS plot created with the following code (other packages than statsmodels are fine as well).

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.random(100) * 0.2
lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y, x, frac=0.1)

plt.plot(x, y, '+')
plt.plot(lowess[:, 0], lowess[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

I've added an example plot with confidence interval below from the webblog [Serious Stats](https://seriousstats.wordpress.com/tag/loess/) (it is created using ggplot in R).

[image]

Comment: statsmodels lowess doesn't calculate standard errors.

Comment: So much better reason to ask the question...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LOESS doesn't have an explicit concept for standard error.  It just doesn't mean anything in this context.  Since that's out, your stuck with the brute-force approach.

Bootstrap your data.  Your going to fit a LOESS curve to the bootstrapped data.  See the middle of this page to find a pretty picture of what your doing.  http://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s208/node20.html

[image]

Once you have your large number of different LOESS curves, you can find the top and bottom Xth percentile.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This is a very old question but it's one of the first that pops up on google search. You can do this using the loess() function from scikit-misc. Here's an example (I tried to keep your original variable names, but I bumped up the noise a bit to make it more visible)

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from skmisc.loess import loess

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.random(100) * 0.4

l = loess(x,y)
l.fit()
pred = l.predict(x, stderror=True)
conf = pred.confidence()

lowess = pred.values
ll = conf.lower
ul = conf.upper

plt.plot(x, y, '+')
plt.plot(x, lowess)
plt.fill_between(x,ll,ul,alpha=.33)
plt.show()
```

result:

[image: loess smooth with CI]

Comment: Seems like skmisc isn't avaiable on Windows unfortunately.

Comment: Still not available for windows in 2022 unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

For a project of mine, I need to create intervals for time-series modeling, and to make the procedure more efficient I created [tsmoothie](https://github.com/cerlymarco/tsmoothie): A python library for time-series smoothing and outlier detection in a vectorized way.

It provides different smoothing algorithms together with the possibility to computes intervals.

In the case of `LowessSmoother`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tsmoothie.smoother import *
from tsmoothie.utils_func import sim_randomwalk

# generate 10 randomwalks of length 200
np.random.seed(33)
data = sim_randomwalk(n_series=10, timesteps=200, 
                      process_noise=10, measure_noise=30)

# operate smoothing
smoother = LowessSmoother(smooth_fraction=0.1, iterations=1)
smoother.smooth(data)

# generate intervals
low, up = smoother.get_intervals('prediction_interval', confidence=0.05)

# plot the first smoothed timeseries with intervals
plt.figure(figsize=(11,6))
plt.plot(smoother.smooth_data[0], linewidth=3, color='blue')
plt.plot(smoother.data[0], '.k')
plt.fill_between(range(len(smoother.data[0])), low[0], up[0], alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

I point out also that tsmoothie can carry out the smoothing of multiple time-series in a vectorized way. Hope this can help someone